# Wrap resources in a single service in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Recently I found a [**TokenHandler**](https://gist.github.com/nblumoe/3052052) that allows me to send a token on every rest api request. You can find a detailed description here: http://nils-blum-oeste.net/angularjs-send-auth-token-with-every--request/#.UXtYlbVTDIX

I am facing an issue implementing this handler in my project. My project is dealing with a couple of resources, let me just talk of **Post** and **Author**. What I am currently doing is:

```
angular.module('PostService', ['ngResource']).factory(....
angular.module('AuthorService', ['ngResource']).factory(....
```

And I wrap it up in my main app module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['PostService', 'AuthorService']);
```

My question is, where do I setup the TokenHandler? It has to be assigned to a module right? I would assign it to e.g. PostService but I would not be able to use it in AuthorService as a result?

As a consequence of that I have another question. Is it possible to wrap multiple resources in one service like:

```
angular.module('RestService', ['ngResource']).factory(['Post', 'Author'],...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the guidelines in the quoted article, declaring the *TokenHandler* service:

> angular.module('TokenHandler').factory('TokenHandler', function() {...

and configuring each service you need to assign the token to in the following way:

```
angular.module('AService', ['ngResource', 'TokenHandler']).factory('AService', ['$resource', 'TokenHandler', function($resource, tokenHandler) {
    var resource = $resource("http://...", {
        ...
    }, {
        get: {
            method:'GET', 
            params:{
                action:'get'
            }, 
            isArray:false
        },
        ...
    });

    resource = tokenHandler.wrapActions( resource, ["get", ...] );

    return resource;
}]);
```

You only wrap the actions that require the token to be sent.
As to your second question, it wouldn't be a good programming practice and, anyway, a factory just returns one object.

Comment: Aww wait, there is a problem. When I declare the module like you say above I get an error: module TokenHandler not found. Any ideas why?

Comment: Here is the code http://dpaste.com/1075274/ which throws the error, I even have not included the service in any module.

Comment: Just named it UserHandler, the error is no module found: UserHandler

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the *AService* dependency from *TokenHandler*, I've edited my answer.